# why is the loop running into negative even though I have specified for x to be positive?

Tags: python, loops

I am writing code to turn a binary number into an integer- though this is just for context.
The issue I have is with the below code where I am trying to use `i` in two cases:

1. `for I in str(arr_str)`
2. `for I in range(1,x)`

How can I use it in both cases? I'm unsure whether this is possible, so any suggestions how I do this? Would I introduce a variable say `j` and then do `for i in str(arr_str)` and then in the next line have `for j in range(1,x)`?

```
while x>=0:
    for i in str(arr_str):
        if i == '1':
            integer_num += 1*((2**(x-i)))
            x-=1
        else:
            integer_num +=1
            x-=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for `enumerate`:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(str(arr_str)):
```

Then `i` will be *index*, starting from 0, and `ch` will be the character at that index.

Comment: That's so clever, I knew about enumerate but haven't used it much before. Thanks, I know how to move forward now!